# JSP <form action ="POST" > not redirecting to Controller, Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I have just started working on SpringBoot Web application with spring MVC. In my POC am trying to display the values selected on the previous page.

login screen is working fine. once clicked on login button with valid credentials it is being redirected to success.jsp as expected.Now I am expecting ,when i hit the submit button in success.jsp , it would call the controller method [action1() /action2() ] and print the message in console.

Controller Class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String init(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("msg", "Please Enter Your Login Details");
        System.out.println("INIT ====");
        return "login.jsp";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submit(Model model,
            @ModelAttribute("loginBean") LoginBean loginBean) {
        System.out.println("submit22 ====");
        if (loginBean != null && loginBean.getUserName() != null
                & loginBean.getPassword() != null) {
            if (loginBean.getUserName().equals("a")
                    && loginBean.getPassword().equals("a")) {
                model.addAttribute("msg", loginBean.getUserName());
                return "success.jsp";
            } else {
                model.addAttribute("error", "Invalid Details");
                return "login.jsp";
            }
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("error", "Please enter Details");
            return "login.jsp";
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/addDetails",params="submit",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void action1()
    {
        System.out.println("submit block called GET ");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/addDetails",params="submit",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void action2()
    {
        System.out.println("submit block called POST");
    }
```

login.jsp

```
<form:form name="submitForm" method="POST">

    <div align="center">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="userName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div style="color: red">${error}</div>

    </div>
</form:form>
```

success.jsp

```
<form:form action="/addDetails" method="post">
     <table>
      <tr>
      <td><form:label path = "name">Name : </form:label></td>
        <td>
             <input type="text" name="name">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
           <td><form:label path = "gender">Gender : </form:label></td>
           <td>
              <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" > Male 
              <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female
              <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
           </td>
        </tr>         
      <tr>
      <td>
              <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" name ="submit"/>
       </td>
       </tr>       
     </table>
</form:form>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>SampleWebApp</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring/application-config.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

mvc-config.xml :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc   
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd"> 

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.dm.springboot"></context:component-scan>
<bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <!-- Example: a logical view name of 'showMessage' is mapped to '/WEB-INF/jsp/showMessage.jsp' -->
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: So what was error when running? Please clarifying that

Comment: No error in console. its just not redirecting. Also can you let me know if application name by default set to context path ? or it has to be configured somewhere? and if its not configured , is there any problem ?